# Does linking external JavaScript in HTML document take up bandwidth?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For instance, my HTML document looks like:

```
<html>
<head> ... </head>
<body>
    <script ...></script>
    // more scripts here, excuse the syntax
</body>
</html>
```

If I remove some of the inline JavaScript, would that free up bandwidth? Moreover, would removing the inline JavaScript *and* removing the actual JavaScript source files free up even more bandwidth when my page loads?

I'm a bit new to HTML/JavaScript/network concepts and am unsure about how this works. I believe I could use Chrome developer tools to test the load time and infer that lower load time means use of less bandwidth, but I'd like to check with more experienced folks.

EDIT: A follow-up question for specificity: does the act of linking take up bandwidth? Assume we're ignoring the fact that text in HTML takes up some bandwidth.

EDIT 2: After testing the load time and looking at the KBs transferred with Chrome developer tools, the change in KBs transferred when removing the linking seemed to make no difference.

Comment: Well, yeah, if the browser has to load less data (less text=less data), it would free up more bandwidth

Comment: Are you asking whether sending fewer bytes in your file will save bandwidth?

Comment: @SLaks I'm not trying to.

Comment: @LucaKiebel Oh I see. Let me add to my question to make it more specific.

Comment: I've edited the question.

Comment: Anything that is not cached will take up bandwidth.  Furthermore, until it is cached, there will technically be more time spent retrieving multiple files vs a single file as each request encurs network latency and has to process their own handshakes and all that networking business involved.

Comment: "The act of linking" is a meaningless term.  HTTP responses, by definition, consume bandwidth.

Comment: @SLaks Oh, I didn't know that. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: How did you think it worked? Did you expect to magically send data to the browser without using bandwidth?

Comment: @SLaks My idea of bandwidth was wrong. I thought bandwidth referred to the maximum amount of data that could be sent, and that the server-side or client-side (or whatever) were fast enough that they could process the data instantaneously. Learning by experience... and StackOverflow.

Comment: @Taplar The first edit was another question, the second edit was the result of testing the scenario I previously presented. *Thank you* for your concern.

Comment: So is there still a question to be answered?

Comment: @Taplar You tell me. You're the one asking more questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline JavaScript would increase size of your HTML file, and external `.js` files also take up some bandwidth to go through network, so in short, answer is yes. You would save up some bandwidth if you were to remove some JavaScript, but you would have to remove a lot of it to save significant amount of bandwidth.

To save on bandwidth you can [leverage browser caching](https://varvy.com/pagespeed/leverage-browser-caching.html)  instead.

Basically, you would keep all your JavaScript, but you just wouldn't be sending it every time user requests your page. Instead it would be kept in clients browser for some time.

Another way to reduce size of JavaScript files without removing any part of it is minification/uglification of code, so you can take a look into that as well

Comment: Along with minification, gzipping the .js files and configuring your server to serve the gzipped version if the browser supports it (almost all do) can lead to very significant bandwidth savings. If you set up a build system for your site you can automate the minification and gzipping quite easily. You can serve just about any text file gizpped too, including your HTML pages and CSS, etc.